# Import Issue Java TTest

Tags: java, import, apache-commons

I am trying to run a TTest in my program and importing the class necessary for importing it isn't working.

This is where I heard of the class
http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/index.html?org/apache/commons/math3/stat/inference/TTest.html

I tried:

```
import java.lang.Object.org.apache.commons.math3.stat.inference.TTest;
```

and

```
import org.apache.commons.math3.stat.inference.TTest;
```

and a few combinations of those that didn't work either.

If you know how to do it please let me know!

Inside I am constructing using

```
TTest test = new TTest();
```

so if that is the error just let me know!

Comment: Is `commons-math` in your classpath? What is exactly the error you get?

Comment: I don't know what putting commons-math in my classpath means.  :(

Comment: I getException in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
 TTest cannot be resolved to a type
 TTest cannot be resolved to a type

 at MatchTx.weightPathways(MatchTx.java:287)
 at MatchTx.main(MatchTx.java:37)

Answer (score 1):

`import org.apache.commons.math3.stat.inference.TTest;` is the correct way to import the [`TTest`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/javadocs/api-3.2/org/apache/commons/math3/stat/inference/TTest.html) class from [commons-math](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/).

Since `TTest` belongs to an external library (`commons-math`), you have to download it and tell Java where to find it to build and run your program, this is the classpath and it should be defined if you are using a class which does not belong to the default standard Java classes. If you are not aware of classpath and external libraries in Java, you should definitively [read and *google* about the subject](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html).

Comment: Then you can accept the answer if it answers your question. You (and I) will get reputation points.